# Is it possible to avoid using templates from Javascript in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm currently building a big web application using AngularJS. I just decided to switch from Angular 1.5 to Angular 2 because I needed some performance improvements regarding change detection.

It seems like there is no ng-app equivalent in Angular 2. In NG1 I just put my HTML code into the index.html file. This allowed me to minify it (like the templates) but also to have it load instantly. Now with this modular NG2 approach, it seems I have to use a Component with the template or the templateURL attribute. The problem with templateURL is that it adds a significant load delay (which wouldn't be a problem on any sub-views on my site, but it is a problem on my main page with its navigation, which must be available as soon as possible), because it requires the browser to load the files sequentially instead of parallel (it first has to load and execute the Javascript file before it begins loading the template). The problem with just using the template-attribute is that I can not minify the contents.

Of course there also is the option to use Browserify or Webpack, but I want to avoid using these, as they add huge amounts of complexity and I actually don't want all my javascript files being combined. I would have 100s of entry points which I all had to set manually.

So, is there a way to just use directives/components straight from the index.html? So that I can do it like in Angular 1, I just specify `<ng-app>{{sampleData}}</ng-app>` straight from the index.html instead of first loading another template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gulp plug in  https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template   that you can use for this purpose. It will convert templateurl to template. I'm using that in my project. 
If you see the document, there is a way to minify also(using preprocessor functions). I haven't used that though.